# Haskell: any debugShow function?

Tags: debugging, haskell

I want to use `Debug.Trace.trace` to print something which I know is a `Show`. Just like I would do in Python etc.

One solution is to add "`Show a =>`" to the signature of the function where I want to put the trace, and to any function calling it, etc.

But it would had been much nicer if I could use some `debugShow` function which calls `show` if the value has one, otherwise returns `"--no show--"` or something.

Here's my failed attempt to define a `DebugShow` (GHC rejects `"Duplicate instance declarations"`):

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances, OverlappingInstances #-}

class DebugShow a where
  debugShow :: a -> String

instance Show a => DebugShow a where
  debugShow = show

instance DebugShow a where
  debugShow = const "--no show--"
```

Some kind of "unsafe cast" would also solve my problem.

Any advice?

Note - This is only for debugging purposes. I'm not using this in any finished code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not absolutely certain of this, but I think this is impossible without adding a class context to the entire call chain between the use site and the call site where each type variable is determined. The reason for this is operational: at least in GHC, each class is implemented by a dictionary. So at the use site we need a `Show` dictionary for `a` if one exists at all. But to get this we need it to have been passed down from the site where `a` was determined, and this requires something to be in the signature of all the intermediate functions.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you want some variant of:

```
traceShow :: (Show a) => a -> b -> b
traceShow = trace . show
```

defined in Debug.Trace

The constraint "calls show if the value has one, otherwise returns "--no show--" or something" is a hard one. You'll need overlapping (and incoherent) instances, I think, to define a default Show for all types (Perhaps via unsafeCoerce, or via vacuum).

Comment: @dons: when you say via vacuum, what do you mean? is that a way to say that it can't be done?

Comment: @yairchu I mean vacuum: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vacuum/0.0.95/doc/html/GHC-Vacuum.html#v%3Avacuum   which renders heap objects (i.e. doesn't need a Show dictionary)

Answer (score 2):

Just use a default method implementation in class DebugShow.  This should do exactly what you want:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

class DebugShow a where
  debugShow :: a -> String
  debugShow = const "--no show--"

instance Show a => DebugShow a where
  debugShow = show
```

Answer (score 1):

"unsafe cast" is known as [`unsafeCoerce`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Unsafe-Coerce.html#v:unsafeCoerce).  Please observe the warnings in its [documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/ghc-prim/GHC-Prim.html#v%3AunsafeCoerce%23); it's an easy way to cause crashes and other foul behavior.

Comment: @ephemient: thanks. in this case it seems I can use 'unsafeCoerce' to "cast" to a specific type, but I want to "cast" it to the same unknown type and add `Show` to its context. I tried to define "`debugShow = show . unsafeCoerce`" but that fails because of "`Ambiguous type variable`"